# cakephp 2.4.6 and array output

Tags: cakephp

When I am try pick a manufacturer name and upload the manufacturer logo image I want the image name to the manufacturer name. But the file name is always Array.

Can someone check the below code and tell me what is wrong?

View.ctp

```
<fieldset>
                        <label>Manufacturer</label>
                        <?php


                        echo $this->Form->input('manufacturer_id', array('options' => $manufacturers));
                        ?>
                    </fieldset>
```

controller.ctp

```
$manufacturer_name=$this->Manufacturer->findById($product_data['Product']['manufacturer_id']);
$new_image_name =  $manufacturer_name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cakephp 2 returns query result in the form of **[ModelName]** array.

You can access any field by using [ModelName][fieldName]

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )

    [AssociatedModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )
)
```

You can access Manufacturer name as (assuming manufacturer name is stored in **name** column)

```
$new_image_name =  $manufacturer_name['Manufacturer']['name'];
```

For further reading:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: You have nailed it my friend!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer specifically as I don't know what the `Manufacturer` object contains but... try this, although it's a bit hacky. In `controller.ctp` add the `print_r` line:

```
$manufacturer_name=$this->Manufacturer->findById($product_data['Product']['manufacturer_id']);
$new_image_name =  $manufacturer_name;
print_r($manufacturer_name);
```

It should show you how the `$manufacturer_name` variable is composed and then allow you to select what you're actually looking for, which I suspect will be something like:

```
$new_image_name =  $manufacturer_name['some_index'];
```